# .net Windows service crashes, mscorwks.dll faulting module is logged in the system events, how to track it down?

Tags: c#, .net

I get faulting application errors from time to time as follows:

Faulting application name: Service.exe, version: 1.0.4911.21253, time stamp: 0x51b851fb
Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.5456, time stamp: 0x4ef6c091
Exception code: 0xc0000005

Could you please tell if I could modify the windows service to log the full stackTrace?

EDITed:

I have also found that prior to that error the following one is logged:

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: Your best bet would be to add logging with something like log4net.

Comment: I have edited the original post

Comment: "This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." Have you tried running a memory diagnostic tool?

Comment: That's a hard crash, an AccessViolationException.  You'll need to obtain a minidump of the crashed process and use an unmanaged debugger like Windbg with sos.dll to diagnose it.  That's not going to be easy.